# The Skia does not support the platform iOSDevice64 in this RAD Studio version

Tags: ios, delphi, skia, rad-studio, skia4delphi

When opening my project, I get the following message:

> The Skia does not support the platform iOSDevice64 in this RAD Studio version
> To avoid problems, disable Skia in this project (Project menu > Disable Skia) or, if you want to disable it just in a specific platform, set the define directive "SKIA_DISABLED" in the project settings of this platform. In both cases, be sure you are not using any Skia units, otherwise you will get a "runtime error" on startup of your application.

But I don't know what to do. I want Skia enabled. I don't know how to set the "SKIA_DISABLED" directive.

What should I do? Any help?

Comment: Which version of RAD Studio are you using? Are you using the recently released 12.0 Athens with [built-in Skia integration](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/What%27s_New#Skia_Integration), or are you using an earlier version with Skia4Delphi installed manually?

Comment: I am using RAD Studio 10.x for this project. It's manually installed.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version, for iOS?

Comment: In the Project Options, you should be able to add `SKIA_DISABLED` to the "Conditionals" list for your build configuration(s) for iOSDevice64. But, you really need to upgrade if you intend to continue supporting modern mobile devices.  Mobile requirements change pretty frequently, and older compilers can quickly become obsolete and not be able to deploy to App Stores anymore.